# How to set MaxRecvDataSegmentLength on Solaris 11 iSCSI target (COMSTAR)

Tags: solaris, iscsi

Our system is Solaris 11.1 with COMSTAR iSCSI target. We would like to increase MaxRecvDataSegmentLength iSCSI parameter on the target but can't find a way to do it, although certain blog records on the Internet state it is possible. If so, how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
# iscsiadm modify target-param -p maxrecvdataseglen=65535 TARGET
```

(-p or --login-param)

```
# iscsiadm list target-param -v TARGET
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/iscsiadm-1m.html#REFMAN1Miscsiadm-1m

Comment: `iscsiadm` manages iSCSI initiators on a per target basis so it's a client-side utility. It does not list or change anything on the target unfortunately.